# .ontapGesture locking the segment picker

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

So I'm pretty new to swift, and I need to make an app using swiftUI. I've build some of it but there is this screen that is a form. I wanted to find a way to when the user clicked outside of the keyboard it closes. I did find a way creating a function for it, but I have to call it with .onTapGesture and this makes the segment control stop working. Any idea on how to work around this?
The function I made to close the keyboard, I call it in the end of the Form view :

```
extension View {
    func hideKeyboard() {
        let resign = #selector(UIResponder.resignFirstResponder)
        UIApplication.shared.sendAction(resign, to: nil, from: nil, for: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: Which iOS versions do you support?

Comment: The minimum is iOS 16.4